# How to allow users to change approver in approval process on record

Tags: approval-process, approval-step

so, here is my problem: I have records which are sent for approval, but the person who should approve them doesn't seems to have the time to do so, and so the records are 'stuck' in Waiting for Approval status. The delegated approver in this case is also unable to handled these records approvals.
The solution that we are trying to implement is to allow small group of users to reassign the approval to someone else, if they notice that the record is waiting for approval too long. However, I can't seem to find a way to do that. Do you know how to allow a group of users to reassign approval process to someone else?

Thank you all in advance,
Lior.

Answer (score 2):

I see there are options to do this however you need to make sure a few things.
The smaller group that will reassign the approval process will have to have Admin Privileges or it's the Approver who has the right to reassign an approval request. They can reassign the approval to a different user using the advanced approval screen.

On the flip side, you can build some custom logic with a button to do a bulk action using an apex controller wired to a button.

To change the Approver for an Approval request you have to update the `ActorId` field on the `ProcessInstanceWorkItem` object with the Id of the user you want to reassign.

The code snippet would look like the below -

```
ProcessInstanceWorkItem proInst = [SELECT Id, ActorId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkItem WHERE Id = 'YOUR SUBMITTED APPROVAL PROCESS ID'];
proInst.ActorId = 'Your Target new User ID for Re-Assignment';
update proInst;
```

Let me know if you are looking for something else.